# Show that $\arg_\tau(z)$ is not holomorphic in $\mathbb{C}^{\circ}_{\tau}$

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $\tau \in \mathbb{R}$, define $\mathbb{C}^{\circ}_{\tau} =${$z \in \mathbb{C}: \tau \notin \arg(z)$}. Show that $\arg_\tau(z)$ is not holomorphic in $\mathbb{C}^{\circ}_{\tau}$.

This is how I did it,

$$z = x+iy = re^{i\theta}$$

$$\arg(z) = \arctan\left(\frac{y}{x}\right) = u(x,y) + iv(x,y)$$

It's not holomorphic if it doesn't satisfy the Cauchy-Riemann equations. But $v(x,y) = 0$, which would mean that $\arg(z)$ is a constant number. I don't know how to show that it's not holomorphic in $\mathbb{C}^{\circ}_{\tau}$.

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE! <> Could you please proofread carefully to make sure all the logical negations are correct? Particularly, in the definition of the set was "$z \in \mathbf{C}$" meant, and maybe the last sentence is not what was intended...? (Nothing in the question asks to show anything is holomorphic anywhere.) <> Whatever typos there may be, (i) a non-constant real-valued function is not holomorphic, and (ii) if it matters, the asserted arctan formula is only correct in the right half-plane.

Comment: Hi @AndrewD.Hwang, thank you so much! I will fix my mistakes.

Comment: By $\tau \notin \arg (z)$, do you mean $\tau \neq \arg (z)$? What is $\arg_\tau (z)$?

Comment: The formula $\arg(z)=\arctan(y/x)$ is true only if $x>0$. See [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Argument_(complex_analysis)#Computing_from_the_real_and_imaginary_part).

Comment: As you note, $\operatorname{arg}$ would have to be constant in the stated region, which it isn't. :)

Comment: Please note that it is asking about $\arg_\tau z$, not $\arg z$. So the first thing you need to check is what it means by $\arg_\tau$. I have my guess, but guessing is not what you should be doing here. Go look up the definition.